# Hierarchical snapshots strange behaviour

Tags: btrfs

I have divided my drive into two btrfs paritions: one is mounted as `/ (dev/sda1)`, second one as `/home (/dev/sda2)`.

I made my initial snapshot of `/home`:

```
mkdir -p /home/snapshots/mnt
mount -o subvolid=0 /dev/sda2 /home/snapshots/mnt
btrfs subvolume snapshot /home /home/snapshots/mnt/snapshots/init
```

After that I made my `init` snapshot default and rebooted the system.
Because I wanted the `init` snapshot to stay clean I decided to make a snapshot of it and call it `current`:

```
mount -o subvolid=0 /dev/sda2 /home/snapshots/mnt
btrfs subvolume snapshot /home /home/snapshots/mnt/snapshots/current
```

It worked, but after making `current` default subvolume and rebooting the system I noticed that `ls` on `/home/snapshots` give me unexpected results:

```
# ls /home/snapshots 
init mnt
# ls /home/snapshots/init
#
```

The question is: why is the `init` folder visible?
My intuition is that the `init` snapshot is created on subvolume with id 0 and should be visible only from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When snapshot of a given subvolume is made, all subvolumes contained in it (in the sense of being attached in the file tree) are treated like empty directories. Hence the behaviour. You can just remove them from the snapshot, no data loss here :)